# Time domain basis

Tags: fourier, linear-algebra

I have some troubles with understanding time domain,  not on the intuitive level, but in math terms.

For  example I have a vector signal $$ x = [x_0,x_1,x_2,...,x_{N-1}]$$
I understand that generally when we describe our signal in the form of a vector,  we just put our information in a convenient form for further manipulation.

i can change the basis to the  frequency domain via DFT analysis, and then I can get back (to time domain) with DFT synthesis. DFT synthesis just multiply my complex amplitude on complex sinudoids with different weights $w$. And it's perfectly correct on physics level like we just sum some periodic functions with different amplitudes.

But when we are talking about change of basis, we have in mind:

$$\alpha_k = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \beta_n \langle w^{(k)},w^{(n)} \rangle$$

where: $w^{(k)}$ - the first basis ; $w^{(n)}$ - the second basis ; $\alpha_k$ - expansion coefficients in second basis; $\beta_n$ - expansion coefficients in first basis;

where:$$x_n = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\beta_nw_n$$ - this is our information vector in time domain;
and
basis for frequency domain is $$w^{(k)} = w_k[n] = e^{\frac{2\pi i}{N}kn}$$

and my question is:
do I understand right that time domain basis is a canonical basis for N-dimensional linear space like that:
$$\hat{e}^{(k)} = \delta[n-k]$$

Comment: the first sum upper limit is probably N-1 ?

Comment: Yep, sry, my fail. Already corrected)

Comment: also please use $\alpha$ and $\beta$ (i.e. different symbols) for coefficients in different bases

Comment: @Fat32 done, but why? It's canonical notation in literature

Comment: ok. it's not mandatory. But in this field (dsp) we deal with signals like $x[n]$,  $h[n-k]$ etc, where index $n$ and $k$ refers to elements of the same signal. It may cause confusion referring to $k$-th element and $n$ th element of some signal etc. Also the same applies for **base** names as well, i.e. $\phi$ vs $\lambda$ could be etc. **Finally** your answer *seems* yes...

Comment: @Fat32 okay, sounds reasonable (about notation) thx for recommendation. And thanks for the answer)

Comment: Any more hints required?

Answer (score 1):

Given a  $N$-dimensional linear space, the Kronecker $\delta[\cdot]$ basis is the most natural basis for describing discrete sampled signals, with

\begin{align}
\delta_0 & = [1,0,0,\ldots,0]\\
\delta_1 &= [0,1,0,\ldots,0]\\
\delta_{N-1} &= [0,0,0,\ldots,1]
\end{align}

and hence can be called canonical. You can refer  to [What does 'canonical' mean?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/26840/15892) for global ideas about the canon, with [one answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/26855/15892):

> The etymology refers to the canon, as a rule or a body of rules, or
>   axiomatic or universal standards. It exists in arts: sculpture, music,
>   script writing, etc. The notion of canon law is also used in the
>   domain of religion.
>
> In mathematics, and engineering, a canonical form is, similarly, a
>   preferred notation, or a unique and natural form, or representation,
>   of an object, a formula. For instance, a canonical basis is a basis of
>   a vector space (an algebraic structure in general) that refers to a
>   precise context, like the standard basis defined by the Kronecker
>   delta.

However, I dare to say that this is disconnected from a "discrete-time signal" concept. You could consider a space where complex sines would be discretized and sampled in a frequency domain, and the canonical basis would be exactly the same. In this case, the same basis would be canonical, in that it represents well "frequency Diracs".

Wikipedia entry on [canonical basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_basis) somewhat agrees with that (first item):

> In mathematics, a canonical basis is a basis of an algebraic structure
>   that is canonical in a sense that depends on the precise context:
>
> - In a coordinate space, and more generally in a free module, it refers to the standard basis defined by the Kronecker delta.